# Is it correct/valid design to set a focus on a "readonly" field after page load

Tags: html, css, accessibility

Right now I am setting the focus on the very first editable **input field**, during page load.

In terms of page accessibility,  If the very first element is **"read-only"** input field then is it valid or meaningful to set the focus on the **input field** with cursor disabled ?

Comment: Look at this from user perspective - does it provide any meaningful use case?

Answer (score 1):

The question you should be asking is should you interfere with the user focus at all?

You may think it useful to automatically focus the first input (whether it is read-only or not) but this may not be as useful as you think.

When the page loads the user is *expecting* to have to use your skip link (I assume you have one, if not add it) to bypass the menu and get to the content of the page. However they may not want to as they may want to check they are on the correct page through breadcrumbs, menu position (assuming you mark the current page in some way) etc.

I am also assuming you have a `<H1>` on the page to reinforce that they are where they think they are on the site so they would expect to see that also.

If they are filling in a multi-page form then they will use screen reader shortcuts to look for the next form, if you have more than one on the page (search box, quick contact etc.) they would end up navigating away from your form by mistake instead of landing on it.

Now assuming that even with all of the above it is actually a better user experience to focus the first input (I am not saying it isn't, just pointing out the above considerations) should you focus the first 'read-only' input.

The answer is nearly always yes.

If a non screen reader user will see that information before they see information that requires inputting / editing then a screen reader user should also see it first.

The only exception to this would be if all of those read-only fields are a summary of everything entered so far in a multi part form.

In that case (as a rough rule, yet again use your own judgement) you should still provide that information first but make sure there is a heading / legend / field set title etc. that indicates that this is previously entered information and provide an easy way to skip to the fields that require input.

It is perfectly acceptable to have 'skip links' within the document, they don't have to just be for menus.

You do this so that they have the option to check previously entered information is correct and know it is available on the page to refer back to, but also don't have to tab past every single field if they don't want to check the information entered previously.

As with everything in accessibility, each use case is slightly different so the only real answer is 'it depends', but hopefully the above will help guide your thought process on what will work best.

This is where user testing is your best friend, only real world screen reader users who do not know your site design and layout will let you see if you made the best choice / which scenario works best.